# Is there a way to get a parrallel mouse cursor between two PCs?

Tags: mouse

Is there a way to make one wireless/bletooth mouse move parrallel between two computers at the same time.

I don’t want one of those Logitech mice that you can only switch between three computers and not work at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch a mouse (and keyboard) with a switch (KVM) or a special mouse that switches (as you note).

But an installed mouse on one computer will not activate in any way on another computer.

USB Keys pair with the mouse and another computer with the same kind of USB Key pairs with a different mouse (and keyboard). We have this kind of setup at numerous clients. Mice, keyboards, computers are near each other (within USB range)

But the same mouse will not work a different computer at the same time.